# Slide Toggle two different css states

Tags: jquery

This works awesome when I need it to slide down and up but because of my css there is a double border when its up. So I tried taking out the top border in the main css and adding it after the slide but if someone toggles again its still there. How would I make it so that at first position (when its up) there is no border top and when its at second position (when its down) there is a border top. Here is my code

```
$('.product').click(function() {
  $('.info').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    $('.product').css( "border-top","1px solid #000" );
  });
});
```

Comment: I have not played with jquery for a long time, but i think `slideToggle();` has only animation complete callback. So you would probably need to use `slideUp();` and `slideDown();` for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oqorex/3/edit)

```
$('.product').toggle(function() {
    $('.info').stop(1).slideDown('slow');
    $(this).css( "border-top","1px solid #000" );
}, function(){
    $('.info').stop(1).slideUp('slow');
    $(this).css( "border-top","1px solid transparent" );
});
```

I used `.stop(1)` to clear some animation queue.

Comment: Why slideToggle twice? You should slide up/down in that case i think

Comment: @Malyo Why not? You like the demo? You can use slideToggle and slideUp/down as you whish

Comment: Since that would seem pointless since we don't need to sort of double the action if you know what i mean, 2 triggers for single actions are enough. I like the edited version!

Comment: Thanks @Malyo. The second one is a real-world solution cause the .stop() but I get your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jquery `toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) by creating 2 css classes with respective borders. and toggling them as and when required

Example

```
$('.product').click(function() {
  $('.info').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    $('.product').toggleClass('addBorder');
  });
});​
```

You can check the [live example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYbZs/)

Answer (score 0):

Oh well it's fun to play with jquery :)

Here's my little experiment:

```
$('.product').click(function() {
    if($('.toggled').length > 0){
      $('.info').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $('.product').css( "border-top","none" ).removeClass('toggled');
      });
    }else{
      $('.info').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $('.product').css( "border-top","1px solid #000" ).addClass('toggled');
      });
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kaunt/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.product').click(function() {
  $('.info').slideToggle('slow', function() {
      $('.product').css( "border-top","1px solid #000" );
      if(!$('.info').is(':visible')) $('.product').css( "border-top","1px solid transparent" );
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/L5tvB/)**